# Migrate data using FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I use FluentMigrator in my project.
And now I Add new column in table and how I can update data in this column by SQL query?

```
public override void Up()
{
    Alter.Table("Images").AddColumn("Item_id").AsInt32().Nullable();
    //do something like "Update Images img set img.Item_id=(Select i.Id 
    //from Items i where i.Image=img.Id)"
}
public override void Down()
{
    Delete.Column("Item_id").FromTable("Images");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [Insert.IntoTable](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Raw-Sql-Helper-for-inserting-data):

```
Insert.IntoTable("Users").Row(new { Username = "CURRENT_USER" });
```

or `Execute.WithConnection`to insert data using `FluentMigrator`

Comment: `Insert.IntoTable` is insert new row. I want to update existing rows using data in another table.

`Execute.WithConnection` not working because it havent Context and NHibernate cannot find database by connection string `Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.db3; Version=3;`

Comment: are you talking about Nhibernate or schambers FluentMigrator?

Comment: excuse me. FluentMigrator

Comment: You are talking about `schambers` FluentMigrator - not Nhibernates - right? If so, I will remove the Tags and Edit the title.

Comment: I wrote a method that pass into `Execute.WithConnection`

`private void UpdateReferences(IDbConnection dbConnection, IDbTransaction dbTransaction)
 {
   var command=dbConnection.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText=
   @"Update Images set Images.Item_id=(Select Items.Id 
   from Items where Items.Image_id=Images.Id)";
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}`
and get error that FM cannot find DB

Comment: **how I can insert data in this column** , doesn't insert row.

So, you have any ideas what i do wrong with `Execute.WithConnection`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe You can make it simpler for Your case, but I had a more complex issue. I added a new column of varbinary type, where I needed to keep a complex object and I needed to prepare it in c# code. So I couldn't just execute UPDATE combined with SELECT command.

I solved that by adding a static class where I execute SQL SELECT command, then I use retrieved data during migration to prepare UPDATE commands.

The important clue is to use ConnectionString which is accessible directly from FluentMigrator.Migration class and execute own SQL commands to get data, then process it in C# and then simply use Update.Table method of FluentMigrator.

Here is my code (simplified):

DatabaseHelper class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for executing SQL on a Database defined by given ConnectionString
/// </summary>
public static class DatabaseHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Run SQL SELECT on a Database defined by given ConnectionString
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString">Connection string</param>
    /// <param name="sql">Full SQL SELECT command to be executed</param>
    /// <returns>List of rows containing all columns as string[] array</returns>
    public static string[][] SelectList(string connectionString, string sql)
    {

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection($"{connectionString}"))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (!reader.HasRows)
                    return null;

                List<string[]> rowsList = new List<string[]>();

                //save all rows (including all columns) from the response to the list
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //every row has n columns
                    var row = new string[reader.FieldCount];

                    //fill every column
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        row[i] = reader[i].ToString();
                    }

                    //add row to the list
                    rowsList.Add(row);
                }

                reader.Close();
                sqlConnection.Close();

                return rowsList.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    sqlConnection.Close();

                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Migration class:

```
public class Migration123 : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Column("NEW_COLUMN").OnTable("TABLE_NAME").AsCustom("NVARCHAR(255)").Nullable()

        //migrate data from OLD_COLUMN to NEW_COLUMN
        MigrateData();

        ...

    }

    private void MigrateData()
    {
        string[][] rowsArray = DatabaseHelper.SelectList(ConnectionString,"SELECT [ID],[OLD_COLUMN] FROM [TABLE_NAME]");

        //if nothing to migrate then exit
        if (rowsArray == null)
            return;

        foreach (var row in rowsArray)
        {
            //prepare a value which will be inserted into a new column, basing on old columns value
            var someNewValueForNewColumn = row[1] + " (modified)";

            //insert a value into a new column
            Update.Table("TABLE_NAME").Set(new
            {
                NEW_COLUMN = someNewValueForNewColumn 
            }).Where(new
            {
                ID = row[0]
            });
        }
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class <MigrationClassName> : Migration
{
    private readonly ScriptResourceManager _sourceManager;

    public <MigrationClassName>(
        ScriptResourceManager sourceManager)
    {
        _sourceManager = sourceManager;
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
        MigrateData();
    }

    private void MigrateData()
    {
        var script = _sourceManager
           .Read("<FileName>.sql");

        Execute.Sql(script);
    }
}



using System.IO;

public class ScriptResourceManager
{
    public string Read(string name)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(ScriptResourceManager).Assembly;
        var resourcesBasePath = typeof(ScriptResourceManager).Namespace;

        var resourcePath = $"{resourcesBasePath}.{name}";
        using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

## SQL FILE

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```